# How to install ImageMagick header files of specific version?

Tags: linux, imagemagick, redhat, rhel

I am on RHEL and installed ImageMagick from source using the following:

```
yum install -y libpng libpng-devel
curl -LO http://www.imagemagick.org/download/releases/ImageMagick-6.8.9-9.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.8.9-9/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make install
```

I also need to install the header files. How do I do this? The Yum latest repository only has 6.5.4 and if I install those I get version conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Install-unix.txt it says:

```
533    By default, ImageMagick is installs binaries in /../usr/local/bin, libraries  
534   in /../usr/local/lib, header files in /../usr/local/include and documentation
535   in /../usr/local/share. You can specify an alternative installation prefix
536   other than /../usr/local by giving configure the option --prefix=PATH. This
537   valuable in case you don't have privileges to install under the default
538   paths or if you want to install in the system directories instead.
```

So it should already be present.  I verified this with the same version you installed. it is located in $prefix/include/ImageMagick.

Comment: Yes, also verified this. I think the actual problem is that `rmagick` isn't able to located the header files. Thanks.